# How to ensure that domain models are valid?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dozer

I have created two set of models, I have the entities which are persisted to the database and that is used internally in the system. I have also created a set of DTOs of these objects that I use in my REST service.

I am using Dozer to translate between them. What would be the best way to add validation logic and so to ensure that the "real" entities are kept in a valid state?

I know Dozer use the setters so would that mean that all domain logic and validation should be kept in the setters (in a organized manner of course) or should I validate the state of the DTO's in a external service before mapping to an entity? This already sounds like a bad idea so what would be the best approach? Non of those that I mentioned? Please remember that I use Dozer to map the objects if that make any difference in the answer.

Comment: When do yo want to validate them? before save i guess? i would implements a validate method on each domain obj that is called before saving to DB!.  I guess your DTO are soem kind of Compostion or aggregate multiple entities?

Comment: But I would like to validate them as soon as possible. They follow the same class hierachy as the entities.

Comment: Have you consider avoiding the creation of DTO's ,... Using only your entities as DTO.  Just Like in Ruby on Rails.  Personal note: i hate duplicating object by layer.  If you want to Validate as soon as possible, then you could use a builder pattern that validate at build() time from your Json/xml/etc coming from the request.

Comment: I have considered it, but it is not an option on this project. When I mean as fast as possible I mean; the real objects may be used before they are persisted. I don't want objects in illegal states in the system.